# Is travelling salesman problem with integer weight NP-hard?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, np-complete

I wonder if travelling salesman problem remains to be NP-hard with an additional constraint that the edge weight is integer.

Comment: To prove this, it seems easy to deal with rational number since every rational number W can be represented as A/B. We can multiply B for every edge weight to make rational number W to be an integer A.

Comment: I would think that it would.  I don't have a proof, but I don't see now the additional constraint makes things any easier.

Comment: If you can solve this version in polynomial time you can solve the general version in polynomial time, by approximating the weights sufficiently well.

Comment: The original problem is NP hard (as it is about finding whether a Hamiltonian cycle exists) and so this one would be too (finding the lowest-cost Hamiltonian cycle)

Comment: Thanks for the intuition, Sean Hill. The NP-hardness of the original problem is proved by reducing the Hamiltonian cycle problem to it. The same reduction can be done to the new TSP problem with the integer weight constraint. Is that right?

Comment: I imagine so, because you could reduce this version by setting all the integer weights to 0 and that would be the same thing

Comment: @SeanHill Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The travelling salesman problem already has integer edge weights! For example, in Garey & Johnson, *Computers and Intractability*, the problem is defined as follows:

> **TRAVELLING SALESMAN**
>
> INSTANCE: A finite set $C=\{c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_m\}$ of "cities", a "distance" $d(c_i,c_j)\in Z^+$ for each pair of cities $c_i,c_j\in C$, and a bound $B\in Z^+$ (where $Z^+$ denotes the positive integers).
>
> QUESTION: Is there a "tour" of all the cities in $C$ having total length no more than $B$?

In order for a problem to be in NP, it must be possible to verify a solution to the problem in time that's polynomial in the size of the problem description. For integer distances, it's obvious that this can be done. For fractional distances, it's not obvious: if you try to convert them all to a common denominator, how big might the denominator get? I think it can be done (the common denominator has size that's polynomial in the size of the problem description), but it's an awkward complication and it's easy to see why the problem is usually defined with integer distances.